# Cannot determine a partition for slot

Tags: java, redis, redis-cluster, lettuce

During certain redis operations, I am facing PartitionSelectorException.

`Caused by: io.lettuce.core.cluster.PartitionSelectorException: Cannot determine a partition for slot 12004.    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.PooledClusterConnectionProvider.getWriteConnection(PooledClusterConnectionProvider.java:164)     at io.lettuce.core.cluster.PooledClusterConnectionProvider.getConnectionAsync(PooledClusterConnectionProvider.java:149)     at io.lettuce.core.cluster.ClusterDistributionChannelWriter.doWrite(ClusterDistributionChannelWriter.java:170)  at io.lettuce.core.cluster.ClusterDistributionChannelWriter.write(ClusterDistributionChannelWriter.java:103)    at io.lettuce.core.RedisChannelHandler.dispatch(RedisChannelHandler.java:218)   at io.lettuce.core.cluster.StatefulRedisClusterConnectionImpl.dispatch(StatefulRedisClusterConnectionImpl.java:216)     at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisAsyncCommands.dispatch(AbstractRedisAsyncCommands.java:676)     at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisAsyncCommands.get(AbstractRedisAsyncCommands.java:960)  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor425.invoke(Unknown Source)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at io.lettuce.core.cluster.ClusterFutureSyncInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(ClusterFutureSyncInvocationHandler.java:122)     at io.lettuce.core.internal.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:80)     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy254.get(Unknown Source)  at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceStringCommands.get(LettuceStringCommands.java:68)`

Code Configuration

`ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions topologyRefreshOptions = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()`
`.enablePeriodicRefresh(Duration.ofSeconds(30))`
`.enableAllAdaptiveRefreshTriggers()`
`.build();`

`ClientOptions options = ClusterClientOptions.builder()`
`.disconnectedBehavior(ClientOptions.DisconnectedBehavior.REJECT_COMMANDS)`
`.autoReconnect(true)`
`.topologyRefreshOptions(topologyRefreshOptions)`
`.build();`

`GenericObjectPoolConfig genericObjectPoolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();`
`genericObjectPoolConfig.setMinIdle(8);`
`genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(16);`
`genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(16);`
`LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()`
`.poolConfig(genericObjectPoolConfig)`
`.clientOptions(options)`
`.clientResources(clientResources)`
`.build();`

Environment

Lettuce version(s): [6.1.5.RELEASE]

Redis version: [5.0.6]

Shards: 6

Number of nodes: 12

Analysis

Redis cluster is healthy, all the metrics are as expected.

So, could you give me some suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: hi, have you fixed this?

Comment: yes, there was an issue in the library. ref :(https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/2252)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I solved it by deleting and restarting my Kubernetes pods. It's possible that just a restart of Spring Boot would have also worked.